# Is there a method for determining the upper and lower boundaries of an single/double/triple integral without graphing the function?

Tags: integration

I've always relied on my calculator to graph the functions for me. Is there a way I can determine the upper/lower boundaries without looking at a graph?

For example, the function $z = 18-2x^2-2y^2$ above the $z$-axis

Comment: Do you mean $18-2(x^2-y^2)$ or $18-2(x^2+y^2)$ ?

Comment: The former. That was a mistake on my part

Comment: For that one, it is trivial if you use cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: @igknighton Are you sure you don't mean the latter? As long as $y\gt x$ the former surface is unbounded.

Comment: http://s24.postimg.org/teq4ly2b9/yis.png It's from this problem

Comment: What you have typed is not the same as your link. The link doesn't have brackets. Your question does.

Comment: I updated the question according to your link. 

Is there a reason why you don't want to look at a plot? That's the easiest way to me.

Comment: It's because I don't know how to figure out what a function looks like on a graph, which is why I always used a calculator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the general question there is no one method for determining the bounds of an integral. It will depend upon the problem. Visualisation is important and this could be achieved graphically as you suggest via your calculator or algebraically by inspecting the function.

To tackle the example problem algebraically consider the boundary, we need $z=0$.

So $18-2x^2-2y^2=0$

$18=2x^2+2y^2$

$9=x^2+y^2$

Looking at this algebraically you may recognise this as the equation of a circle centred at $(0,0)$ with radius 3. That would allow you to visualise the boundary so you can start writing down the bounds. Additionally as it is circular it should hopefully suggest a change to polar coordinates.